# How to display the output in java gui of other java application(not gui)?

Tags: java, swing

please help me to understand how to get an output of regular java tool and display it in textArea component of Java Swing Application?
The regular java application(not gui) can already get a file via cmd and does make an output in console. 
Now, my scenario is  when i'm loading the file in Java Gui , then all data inside will be sent to this java application(jar file not gui) .
I do like this but further i'm stack. Where to send input? and how to get the output stream in order to display it in textArea of  Java Gui application.
The code below is in Java Gui application.

```
    String cmd =MessageFormat.format("java -jar tooling-gott-extended.jar -defaultMID {0} -urls {1} -src {2} -exclude {3}", 
                    comboBoxMid.getSelectedItem(),
                    comboBoxGate.getSelectedItem(),
                    selectedFileTC.toString(),
                    " ");


            ProcessBuilder   pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process  p = pb.start();

BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new 
                                        InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: Where is the string or data you want to write in a `jtextArea`?

Comment: actually the file is selectedFileTc...all data is inside..i just send a path for this file and regular java app(let's call mainAPP) will manage it
When mainAPP will get via cmd above command with path of file, it outputs all information and data. So, do i need to make changes in mainAPP to put in stream instead of console output?

Comment: what's the problem? the gui part (also printing the string on the form)? if so, please post the code for the gui part

Comment: But what about the input, is it enough to send in such way to other java app from gui?

Comment: Given the `ProcessBuilder` is launching a Java app., probably better (and easier) to get the current JVM to launch it directly. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: the problem is not in the gui form , but how to pass from gui to other java app(not gui---mainAPP) like it was via cmd. ....and when the mainAPP makes output in console, then instead of console to put in some stream and return to GUI application

Comment: Who are you replying to? Tip: Add @ItamarGreen (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 0):

i found how to do that , here is the code how to execute it if somebody need it.
But i have now other challenge. I don't see nothing in textArea of gui application until it completes to execute behind in cmd. How to display parallel?

```
String path = "C:\\Eclipse\\workspace_automation\\gui-tool\\java.jar";
    String cmd = MessageFormat.format("java -jar {0}  param1 {1} param2 {2} param3 {3}", path,
            comboBoxMid.getSelectedItem(), comboBoxGate.getSelectedItem(), selectedFileTC.toString());

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", cmd);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    String line;
    while (true) {
        line = r.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(line);
        textArea.append("\n"+line);
    }
```